# Qs about how to ask Qs: putting images in source mwe and and adding output to questions

Tags: discussion, mwe

Three questions from a novice tex stack exchange user:

1. What should I do if I need to include an image in the minimal working example for my question?  Is there some standard image that comes with every LaTeX distribution?  Or do I upload my own?
2. How do I add latex output to a question?
3. What tag should I have used for this question?  I couldn't find an existing one that seemed appropriate.

Comment: This is in the wrong place, but still, I think you deserve a pat on the back for being conscientious enough to ask!

Comment: the graphics package comes with several examples, e.g. `\includegraphics{example-image-a}`

Comment: @MaxNoe mwe package actually

Comment: Oh,  indeed.  Always thought it was part of graphics

Comment: someone will answer once it's migrated, but (1) answered in comments, for (2) just take a screenshot and upload image (until you have enough rep you need to remove the `!` so it makes a link rather than inline image)

Comment: Got it!  Thanks very much!

Comment: See the detailed Answer on Meta http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225

Comment: for 2.: sometimes `\documentclass[convert]{standalone}` is suitable, which makes an png file directly

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This has been answered in comments really but

For (1) for images traditionally you could use

```
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
```

or simply replace the `\includegraphics{...}` by `\rule{3cm}{1cm}` in either case, getting a black rectangle, but most modern installations now include the examples from `mwe` so you can use

```
\includegraphics{example-image}
```

to get an image that people will have locally. It comes with several images of various sizes and shapes, see `texdoc mwe` for details.

For (2) just take a screenshot (and possibly trim it using your system tools) and upload. As an image. Until you have the rep to post an image you can use the image upload form but remove the generated `!` in the markup, which makes it a link. A Higher rep user will put the `!` back.

For (3) use the meta site not the main one:-)

Comment: Na. `example-image` is too dull. `example-image-a` is better. (`example-image-b` is reserved for those who like to dance in the shadow of death and laugh in the face of danger.)

Comment: @cfr ["Ha ha ha ha!"](http://i.stack.imgur.com/CLD3y.jpg)

Comment: Curiosity just killed the cat :(